# No se muestra DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estoy intentando desplegar un `DialogFragment`con un botón para que al presionarlo simplemente desaparezca el diálogo. Se debe mostrar cuando un `PlainText`no tenga texto en él pero no logro hacer que se despliegue. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Por el momento tengo este código:

```
public void registerUser(View view){
   TextView userText = findViewById(R.id.userText);
   if(userText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
         InfoDialog infoDialog = new InfoDialog(getString(R.string.empty_userName));
         infoDialog.showDialog(infoDialog);
    }
}
```

El siguiente es el código de mi clase InfoDialog

```
public class InfoDialog extends DialogFragment {

private String message;

public InfoDialog(){ }

public InfoDialog(String message) {
    super();
    this.message = message;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //Use builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.accept_message, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}

public void showDialog(DialogFragment dialogFragment){
    dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "emptyUserDialog");
}
```

}

Hasta donde he entendido el método onCreateDialog se llama en automático o estoy equivocado?

De antemano muchas gracias.
Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes de llamar al `FragmentManager` en el Activity/Fragment para que se muestre
el DialogFragment:

```
if(userText ....
new InfoDialog().show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya se muestra.